# How to fill or stroke an svg element in a svg sprite.

Tags: css, svg, sass, svg-filters, svg-sprite

I am having issues in seeing the picked element and apply colour to the pick ed element.

For example
 I have an image sprite called untitled.svg in which collection of icons are listed. I want to pick say calendar. I am able to pick the element but I am unable to view or style the picked element calendar. I can see the paths being rendered but unable to style the output.

code sample for calendar

```
<symbol id="calendar" x="160" y="0" class="st1" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="blue" style="
">
    <title>calendar</title>

<path class="st0" d="M181.3,23.3h-10.8c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1V11.5c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h10.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1v10.7  C182.3,22.9,181.9,23.3,181.3,23.3z M170.5,11.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.4,0.4v10.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4h10.7c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.4  V11.5c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.4C181.3,11.2,170.5,11.2,170.5,11.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M172.3,8.8h0.7v1.8h-0.7V8.8z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M178.8,8.8h0.7v1.8h-0.7V8.8z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M175.9,14.6c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4s1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4C177.3,13.9,176.7,14.6,175.9,14.6z   M175.9,12.4c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7s0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7s0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7S176.3,12.4,175.9,12.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M179.5,14.6c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4c0.8,0,1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4  C180.9,13.9,180.3,14.6,179.5,14.6z M179.5,12.4c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7s0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7  S179.9,12.4,179.5,12.4z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M172.3,18.1c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4c0.8,0,1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4  C173.8,17.5,173.1,18.1,172.3,18.1z M172.3,16c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7  S172.7,16,172.3,16z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M175.9,18.1c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4s1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4S176.7,18.1,175.9,18.1z M175.9,16  c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7s0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7S176.3,16,175.9,16z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M179.5,18.1c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4c0.8,0,1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4S180.3,18.1,179.5,18.1z   M179.5,16c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7S179.9,16,179.5,16z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M172.3,21.7c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4s0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4c0.8,0,1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4S173.1,21.7,172.3,21.7z M172.3,19.6  c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7s0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7S172.7,19.6,172.3,19.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M175.9,21.7c-0.8,0-1.4-0.6-1.4-1.4s0.6-1.4,1.4-1.4s1.4,0.6,1.4,1.4S176.7,21.7,175.9,21.7z M175.9,19.6  c-0.4,0-0.7,0.3-0.7,0.7s0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7s0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7S176.3,19.6,175.9,19.6z"/>

</symbol>
```

What am i missing. I am new to using svgs indepth.

Comment: Can you provide more complete code - like your SVG with the use element where you reference the symbol? And the CSS/styles you're trying to style it with? (In general, use elements can't be styled)

Comment: @MichaelMullany I am using <use href="#analytics" x="10" fill="blue" /> to access the element. For testing purposes, if  I remove symbol and use element I get a blank image.

Answer (score 0):

`Symbol` Do not use the tag. Use the `svg` tag instead
This way you can see your drawing on the screen.

Comment: Hi Veysel,Thanks for the quick reply. I tried that, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. The svg file and the html file are in the same folder. I hope this helps.

The document html where I'm using the sprite:

Please note that I'm using `sof.svg#symb`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible;}</style>
</head>
<body>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 14 16" width="50">
    <use xlink:href="sof.svg#symb" fill="red"/>
  </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

The svg document sof.svg

Please note that the `symbol` has an id of `id="symb"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
<symbol viewBox="169 8 14 16" id="symb" style="overflow: visible">
<path class="st0" d="M181.3,23.3h-10.8c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1V11.5c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h10.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1v10.7  C182.3,22.9,181.9,23.3,181.3,23.3z M170.5,11.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.4,0.4v10.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4h10.7c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.4-0.4  V11.5c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.4C181.3,11.2,170.5,11.2,170.5,11.2z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M172.3,8.8h0.7v1.8h-0.7V8.8z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M178.8,8.8h0.7v1.8h-0.7V8.8z"/>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: I cross checked my file and I am using very similar and I have just noticed the paths are being rendered outside the viewBox. Any idea on how I can get it within the viewBox?

Comment: How would I do it: **1**.You change the `symbol` with a `g` (this is temporary) . **2**. In javascript you need to get the size of the bounding box for the `g` by using the `.getBBox()` method. This should return a DOM rect with `x` `y` `width` and `height` properties. **3**. You use those properties to reconstruct the value for the `viewBox` **4**. you change back the `g` to a `symbol`

Comment: Thanks for the information. That's an interesting approach, I will try and will let you know soon